# Document IDs change when files are overwritten

Tags: version-history, document-id, rename

We are using Sharepoint Online 2013. Versioning is activated and functional.

Our problem:

1. I upload a document to SharePoint.
2. I modify a local copy of the document and upload it again overwriting the old document.
3. The document ID of the document has changed! I. e. the "old" document was deleted (I can find it in the recycle bin) and a new document with the same name was created.

Is this the intended process? This is a great issue for us. We have people working with OneDrive and on mobile computers. It happens all the time that documents are modified locally and then uploaded again. Our intention is that these uploaded documents just create a new version of the original file while keeping the original document ID.

Renaming files retains the document ID.

I cannot find any configuration settings that could influence this behaviour. How is this feature working for you?

Comment: I know this is pretty old but my SP 2013 farm creates a new version of the document when you upload a document with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Sharepoint simply expects a replacement as a new file and therefore creates a new document ID. Which is basically correct behaviour in my opinion, because Sharepoint has no way to know if that document is "the same". The only way would be, to update and edit the document directly in it´s Sharepoint-Location.

As far as Office Documents concerns Sharepoint stores all a documents properties also in the document itself. That´s why you can download a file, delete it there and upload it again, and it will still have all the additional metadata you´ve given before. Maybe that works for you too. Did you download the documents from sharepoint before you edited them locally and pushed back? Mabe the document Id then retains the same. However, even than all editors have to download the original from Sharepoint.